# How to add a user to a Group in Kinvey?

Tags: ios, kinvey

I am working on Kinvey iOS SDK. My requirement is that I want to add a user to specific group at registration time.

Actually in my case there are two Group named General & Special & I want to add a user to General group by default. Could any one have any idea that how to implement this with Kinvey iOS SDk?

I found that Andriod SDK has features to add a user to group as given below

```
public void submit(View view) {
        kinveyClient.userGroup().addUserToGroup("13", "15", null new KinveyClientCallback () {
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) { ... }
            public void onSuccess(UserGroupResponse u) { ... }
        });
    }
```

Is there any idea/way to do this in iOS also? Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At present Kinvey does not provide to add a user to a group via iOS SDK.

I made a post on support & below is link of their support response

[Kinvey Support Discussion](https://support.kinvey.com/discussion/201272518/how-to-add-a-user-to-a-group#latest)